Is there a way to sync symbol labels in Ghidra Disassembler with its Decompiler?
I swear that in IDA Pro, when I renamed a stack var in the disassembler, that name would port over to the decompiled view, but this doesn't seem to occur in Ghidra. In fact, in Ghidra, when I try to give the decompiled view variable the same name, it says the name is already used, which is annoying. Is there any way to sync variable names between the disassembler and the decompiler? See the below screenshot, __ptr should be called heap_mem.

